# Alert Message Tradingview

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

How to send alert message if the condition is buy or sell. Currently I have kept the message as below

{"auth-token":"xxxx","key":"TIKCER","value":"-1", "time":"09:15"}

Where I want to pass the value at the time 9:15 is the above code format correct for time?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function that returns the time as you wish and then use the `alert()` function to use this variable in the alert message.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

f_get_time() =>
    s = ""
    
    s := if (hour < 10)
        "0" + str.tostring(hour)
    else
        str.tostring(hour)
    
    s := if (minute < 10)
        s + ":0" + str.tostring(minute)
    else
        s + ":" + str.tostring(minute)

s = f_get_time()

label.new(bar_index, low, s)
alert(s, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

[image]